# How to achieve below code using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I can achieve below,
I have to check last 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account using following formula

```
if ((sum of credits for 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account/
sum debits for 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account)
-sum debits for 30 days from the latest statement date w.r. to account)>0 then YES else NO
```

below are the two columns from two different tables based on which i need to derived formula for each account. And accounts present in both tables A and B.

```
STATEMENT_DATE_LATEST; --from TableA
LATEST_BAL_IN_USD; -- from TableB
```

Note: "/" is Divided by and "-" is Minus sign in above statement

Comment: Help us help you - please share the full table definitions and some sample data

Comment: Why do you think we need to know about `LATEST_BAL_IN_USD`? Nothing in your question *appears* to relate to that field. ???

Comment: @BobJarvis LATEST_BAL_IN_USD is column having transaction amount credit and debit entries in tableB .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, would something like this help?

```
with temp as
  (select a.account,
          sum(case when b.transaction_amount >= 0 then b.transaction_amount end) sum_credits,
          sum(case when b.transaction_amount <  0 then b.transaction_amount end) sum_debits
   from table_a a join table_b b on a.account = b.account
   where b.statement_date > a.statement_date_latest + 30
   group by s.account
  )
select t.account,
       case when (t.sum_credits / t.sum_debits) - t.sum_debits > 0 then 'YES'
            else 'NO'
       end result
from temp t;
```

Comment: This is SQL but the OP has put PL/SQL in the title and tags (which may be a misunderstanding of the terms on their part but we have to assume that they know what they're asking for).

Comment: More to the point a bunch of guesses about the OP's data model and data :)

Comment: @Littlefoot credits and debits are in same column no sign for Credit and "-" in front of number(Transaction Amount) is Debit then how we can do Sum as per it?

Comment: Oh, come on! I'm just trying to help! :) ... I modified code so that it looks at the `transaction_amount` and its sign.

Comment: Respect @Littlefoot -- Guys, Yogesh has not provided proper table structure. Littlefoot is just giving the idea to Yogesh so that he can solve his problem accordingly.

Comment: @Tejash in this case no table structure was required to answer the query that's why i have mentioned TableA and TableB as table name And Mr. LittleFoot helped to to achieve it pretty much. Thank You LittleFoot for your valuable support.

Comment: @Yogesh so you didn't need PL/SQL.